# Column definition needs to be repeated in .js file(for grid)?

Tags: extjs

In exts js designer, let us say a grid is created. So it generates 2 js files:SomeGrid.ui.js and SomeGrid.js.
ui.js file has column definitions and js file has event handling code.
Now if in js file, I wish to add a rowwnumberer like this:

```
initComponent: function() {
SomeGrid.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
this.colModel= new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
columns: [
new Ext.ux.Plugins.PagingRowNumberer({width:30})
]
     }
         )
}
```

Do I need to re-add all the column definitions that are specified in ui.js? With this code, it loads the page jsut with one column:the rowwnumberer.
The existing code re-adds all columns, but there might be a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the the convention recommended by the [Ext Designer](http://www.sencha.com/products/designer/), the column model should be part of the .ui.js file not the .js file.
So ideally, `PagingRowNumberer` column definition should be part of the *SomeGrid.ui.js* file.

If that is not possible for some reason, **yes you will have to repeat** all the column definitions in the SomeGrid.js file because once you do `this.colModel= new Ext.grid.ColumnModel(...` in your *SomeGrid.js*, you are effectively overwriting the `ColumnModel` that was configured in the *SomeGrid.ui.js*

Comment: hm...in java style extend..we can keep properties of the original class..funny that does not happen here

Comment: no, it's not a property of the original class. it is a nested property. think about it as a final property of a property.